# Exclusão desnecessária

Tags: javascript, ajax

Eu tenho uma tabela preenchida com os códigos:

- 1
- 2
- 3

Quando clico no botão excluir registro 1, faz uma pergunta: "deseja excluir o registro?" clico em não. Faço o mesmo para o 2

Mas no 3, clico em "sim"

O problema acontece que está excluindo os três registros.

segue meu `ajax`

```
$(".btn-remove").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
     var rota = $(this).attr("href");

     $('#modal-confirma').modal('show');
     $("#modal-confirma").modal().find(".confirmado").on("click", function(){

        alert(rota);
         $.ajax({
            url: rota,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(resp){
                window.location.href = base_url + resp;
            }
        });
     });
});
```

segue o html do modal

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="modal-confirma">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmação de Exclusão</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            Confirma  exclusão do item?
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-left confirmado"
             data-dismiss="modal">Sim</button>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              Não</button>
            <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>-->
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal -->
```

segue o html da tabela com os registros:

```
<table id="tabelacategoria" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>#</th>
                                    <th>Nome</th>
                                    <th>Descrição</th>
                                    <th>Opções</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                                <?php if(!empty($categorias)): ?>
                                    <?php foreach($categorias as $categoria): ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $categoria->id_categoria; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $categoria->nome; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $categoria->descricao; ?></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="btn-group">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-view" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-default" value="<?php echo $categoria->id_categoria; ?>">
                                                <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
                                            </button>
                                            <a href="<?php base_url()?>categorias/edit/<?php echo $categoria->id_categoria?>" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span></a>
                                            <a href="<?php base_url()?>categorias/delete/<?php echo $categoria->id_categoria ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-remove"><span class="fa fa-remove"></span></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                     <?php endforeach; ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Comment: Voce pode colocar tambem o html 
facilita pra poder te ajdar

Comment: E se clicar direto no 3, sem clicar nos outros antes, o que acontece? Exclui apenas o 3 ou todos também?

Comment: exclui apenas o 3. Editei com o html

Comment: eu tive um problema com modal e o `on('click')`, por algum motivo ele ficava gravando quantas vezes eu abria o modal, e quando ia executar uma ação no modal, a ação era executada varias vezes de acordo com quantas vezes eu abria o modal, para resolver eu troquei o `.on('click')`, para `$("").click()`, para min resolveu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está ao adicionar a função/evento de `click`  no objeto da modal em `.confirmado`, nessa linha especificamente:

```
$("#modal-confirma").modal().find(".confirmado").on("click", function(){
```

Quando você adiciona várias funções em um evento de um mesmo objeto todas elas são despachadas:

```js
$("#teste").on("click", function() {
    console.log("Click 1");
});

$("#teste").on("click", function() {
    console.log("Click 2");
});

$("#teste").click();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="teste" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: #FF0000;"></div>
```

Você precisa usar o comando [`unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) do jQuery para remover as funções anteriores antes de adicionar uma nova:

```
$("#modal-confirma").modal().find(".confirmado").unbind();
$("#modal-confirma").modal().find(".confirmado").on("click", function(){
```

Comment: muito obrigado!!